# need employee details who has only one employment

Tags: sql

need employee details who has only one employment

for example this is the table

```
ID    Name    StartDate    EndDate
1    Fischel    01-May-97    Jan-99
1    Fischel    08-May-92    02-Feb-99
1    Fischel    11-May-92    04-May-10
2    David    10-aug-1980    05-May-1981
3    John    12-sep-1988     06-June-2009
3    John    23-Aug-92    01-Nov-11
```

Output like this

```
2    David    10-aug-1980    05-May-1981
```

Comment: Which RDMS you are using..??

Comment: Show some effort please...

Comment: use group by clause where group having count = 1

Answer (score 0):

```
    Select * from
    (select *,row_number() over (partition by id order by StartDate desc ) as rnm
    from your table
    )Derived_Table
    where Derived_Table.rnm=1;
```

OR

```
select * from table where id in (
select id
from table group by id having count(*) =1) z;
```

Comment: @Patrick ..agree with you but all the standard one like oracle,sql server teradata supports it...and i work one of them..so it was spontaneous reaction...

Comment: The second query has a sub-select trying to return two columns, but only comparing with one column... Remove count(*) from the select-list.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to return a user if same user-name doesn't have any other dates.

```
select ID, Name, StartDate, EndDate
from tablename t1
where not exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                  where t2.id = t1.id
                    and (t2.StartDate <> t1.StartDate
                         or t2.EndDate <> t1.EndDate))
```

Or, have a sub-query that return all id only appearing once:

```
select ID, Name, StartDate, EndDate
from tablename t1
where id in (select id from tablename
             group by id
             having count(*) = 1)
```